# Can we run kubectl form worker/minion node?

Tags: kubernetes

I have my kubernetes cluster setup and I want to check for the nodes from worker/minion node, can we run kubectl form worker/minion node?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you just need to have the proper client credentials and you can run kubectl from anywhere that has network access to the apiserver. See [Sharing Cluster Access with kubeconfig](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/sharing-clusters/) for the instructions to get a `kubeconfig` file onto your worker node.

Comment: This link appears to be outdated as that page doesn't really outline a specific mechanism (such as `scp`) to actually "get a `kubeconfig` file onto your worker node."

Comment: The link is unfortunately broken. Can you provide a new link and if possible some instructions directly in the answer please?

Comment: @Minding - This looks like the new link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/