# did you specify the right host or port? error on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have followed the helloword tutorial on http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/.

When I run:

```
kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/hello-node:v1 --port=8080
```

I get:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Why does the command line try to connect to the localhost?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The issue is that your `kubeconfig` is not right.
To auto-generate it run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials "CLUSTER NAME"
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I was also getting this error after updating the configuration of a cluster. Running this get-credentials command worked for me.

Comment: thanks, for me it asks region name too, `gcloud container clusters get-credentials "CLUSTER NAME" --region=us-central1-a`

Comment: @Alanwagner please update your answer to include  region like Jeyan comment. or Jeyan please can you post yours as answer, and it will be the accepted answer

Answer (score 46):

Make sure your config is set to the project -

```
gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]
```

1. Run a checklist of the Clusters in the account:

```
gcloud container clusters list
```

2. Check the output :

```
NAME           LOCATION       MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP      MACHINE_TYPE  NODE_VE.      NUM_NODES  STATUS
alpha-cluster  asia-south1-a  1.9.7-gke.6     35.200.254.78  f1-micro      1.9.7-gke.6   3          RUNNING
```

3. Run the following cmd to fetch credentials for your running cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials your-cluster-name --zone your-zone       --project your-project
```

4. The following output follows:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for alpha-cluster.
```

5. Try checking details of the node running `kubectl` such as below to list all pods in the current namespace, with more details:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

Should be good to go.

Comment: `$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials <your-cluster-name> --zone your-zone       --project <your-project>` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: What can we do for normal On premises linux cluster

Answer (score 42):

I had same error, this worked for me. Run

`minikube status`

if the response is

```
type: Control Plane
host: Stopped
kubelet: Stopped
apiserver: Stopped
kubeconfig: Stopped
```

run `minikube start`

```
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

You can proceed

Answer (score 14):

After running "kubeinit" command, kubernetes asks you to run following as **regular user**

> mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
>
> sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
>
> sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

But if you run this as a regular user, you will get "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?" when trying to access as a root user and vice versa. So **try accessing "kubectl" as the user who executed the above commands**.

Comment: If doing this from a worker node - make sure the kubeconfig is present 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078305/can-we-run-kubectl-form-worker-minion-node

Comment: Despite installation, the `kubernetes` folder does not exist on my Machine at `/etc/...` so no question of editing `admin.conf`. Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to connect with local-host and end up with same problem, then I found, I need to start a proxy to the Kubernetes API server.

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/http-proxy-access-api/

Answer (score 6):

Reproduce the same error when doing a tutorial from Udacity called Scalable Microservices with Kubernetes https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud615, at the point of Using Kubernetes, Part 3 of Lesson.

Launch a Single Instance:

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx:1.10.0`

Error:

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

How I resolved the Error:

Login to Google Cloud Platform

Navigate to Container Engine
[Google Cloud Platform, Container Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MHNU.jpg)

Click  **CONNECT** on Cluster

Use login Credentials to access Cluster [NAME] in your Teminal

Proceeded With Work!!!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after a reboot, I followed the guide described [here](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/the-connection-to-the-server-host-6443-was-refused-did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port/552)

So try the following:

```
$ sudo -i
# swapoff -a
# exit
$ strace -eopenat kubectl version
```

After that it works fine.

Comment: That is the most bizarre solution imaginable… how on earth does using swap matter? The only thing less likely to matter feels like the next line, `strace`ing, it which just logs syscalls right?

Comment: Well k8s requires swap to be turned off. As for `strace`, it's just a check, it's not part of the soultion

Comment: Hm, looking into it more, it makes sense why k8s wants to not use swap. However, it still doesn't make sense why the client machine (using `kubectl`) needs to have swap turned off; seems like just server machines (nodes in the cluster hosting pods) would require that.

Comment: Ok your point got me thinking. I'm going to take a wild guess here: In all the scenarios including the questions and answers here, they are running `kubectl` in the master node itself, basically where `kubeadm` is running. So in essence I guess we are getting `kubeadm` working and hence the `kubectl` client starts to work. You can verify that as the errors are all pointing to `localhost`

Answer (score 4):

This errors means that `kubectl` is attempting to connect to a Kubernetes apiserver running on your local machine, which is the default if you haven't configured it to talk to a remote apiserver.

Comment: I'm trying to work on local machine and still get this error.. how can solve it (I cannot create a pod)

Comment: I find the solution.. I had to run 'docker run -d...' from: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/

Answer (score 4):

I was getting an error when running

```
sudo kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Finally for my environment this command parameter works

```
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf get pods
```

when executing kubectl as non root.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer, from all above, is to run the commands below:

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/

sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf

export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

Happening because your kubectl is not able to connect to kubernetes server. Run your cluster.

```
minikube start
```

If you want to access service w.r.t your kube config file, you can access it via

```
 kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config  get jobs
```

~/.kube/config : Path of config file, modify w.r.t your file path

Answer (score 3):

Reinitialising gcloud with proper account and project worked for me.

```
gcloud init
```

After this retrying the below command was successful and kubeconfig entry was generated.

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials "cluster_name"
```

check the cluster info with

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of your environment (gcloud or not ) , you need to point your kubectl to  kubeconfig. 
By default, kubectl expects the path as $HOME/.kube/config or point your custom path as env variable (for scripting etc ) 
export KUBECONFIG=/your_kubeconfig_path

Please refer :: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

If you don't have a kubeconfig file for your cluster, create one by referring :: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

It is required to find cluster's ca.crt , apiserver-kubelet-client key and cert.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same trouble since nearly release, seem must use KUBECONFIG explicit

sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/

sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf

export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf

Comment: In my case `current-context` inside `KUBECONFIG` file was changed so it's good idea to try original file `sudo kubectl --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf get nodes`.

Comment: I would say that this is one of the correct answers. Just add admin.conf to the home directory of the regular user.

Answer (score 3):

as an improvement to [Omokahfe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63532511/1290868):

```
minikube status
```

if the response is

```
E0623 09:12:24.603405   21127 status.go:396] kubeconfig endpoint: extract IP: "minikube" does not appear in /home/<user>/.kube/config
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Misconfigured
timeToStop: Nonexistent


WARNING: Your kubectl is pointing to stale minikube-vm.
To fix the kubectl context, run `**minikube update-context**`
```

run

```
minikube update-context
```

then it will show

```
* "minikube" context has been updated to point to 10.254.183.66:8443
* Current context is "minikube"
```

and then

```
minikube status
```

will show

```
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
timeToStop: Nonexistent
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem using a local docker.  The thing to do is check the logs of the containers its spins up to figure out what went wrong.  For me it transpired that etcd had fallen over

```
   $ docker logs <etcdContainerId>
   <snip>
   2016-06-15 09:02:32.868569 C | etcdmain: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:7001: bind: address already in use
```

Aha!  I'd been playing with Cassandra in a docker container and I'd forwarded all the ports since I wasn't sure which it needed exposed and 7001 is one of its ports.  Stopping Cassandra, cleaning up the mess and restarting it fixed things.

Answer (score 2):

If you created a cluster on AWS using kops, then kops creates `~/.kube/config` for you, which is nice.  But if someone else needs to connect to that cluster, then they also need to install kops so that it can create the kubeconfig for you:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws configure get aws_access_key_id)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws configure get aws_secret_access_key)
export CLUSTER_ALIAS=kubernetes-cluster

kubectl config set-context ${CLUSTER_ALIAS} \
    --cluster=${CLUSTER_FULL_NAME} \
    --user=${CLUSTER_FULL_NAME}

kubectl config use-context ${CLUSTER_ALIAS}

kops export cluster --name ${CLUSTER_FULL_NAME} \
  --region=${CLUSTER_REGION} \
  --state=${KOPS_STATE_STORE}
```

Answer (score 2):

try run with `sudo` permission mode 
example  `sudo kubectl....`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone, like myself, came across this thread because of the underlying error in their Cloud Build step while switching from `gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl` to `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk`, you would need to explicitly call `get-credentials` for `kubectl` to work.
My pipeline:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        gcloud container clusters get-credentials --zone "$$CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE" "$$CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER"
        kubectl call-what-you-need-here
options:
  env:
    - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west3-a'
    - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=my-cluster'
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by removing the incorrect environment variable for the kube config with the command

```
unset KUBECONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same below error:

Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Then I just execute below command and found everything working fine.

PS C:> .\minikube.exe start

Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 150.53 MB / 150.53 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
Loading cached images from config file.
PS C:> .\minikube.exe start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when using " Bash on Windows " with azure kubernetes

```
az aks get-credentials -n <myCluster>-g <myResourceGroup>
```

The config file is autogenerated and placed in *'~/.kube/config'* file as per OS (which is windows in my case)

To solve this -
Run from Bash commandline `cp <yourWindowsPathToConfigPrintedFromAbobeCommand> ~/.kube/config`

Answer (score 0):

Fix the Error – The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused

1. Check if the kubeconfig environment variable is exported if not exported

export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf or $HOME/.kube/config

2. Check your  .kube or config in the home directory file. If you did not found it, then you need to move that to the home directory. using the following command

cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/

chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf

export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf

Whenever you are starting Master Node you may require to set the environment variable. Hence it’s a repetitive task for you. It can be set permanently using the following command.

echo 'export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf' >> $HOME/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

when i log in as a root user and run the command kubectl get pods showing error

```
W1021 22:14:58.411448   41786 loader.go:223] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

and without the root user showing pods no error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I started my docker desktop and enabled kubernetes and apply the kubectl command on my terminal, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

in case minikube is used, the following commands might be used to switch to proper profile:

```
minikube profile # get current profile
minikube profile <minikube profile> # set profile
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ***docker desktop***, make sure you have ***Kubernetes enabled***:

```
Go to Preferences > Kubernetes and make sure 'Enable Kubernetes' is checked.
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was simply a full disk, kubectl also gives this error if your disk is full. Sadly, clearing space does not immediately help, a reboot was necessary for me.

Answer (score -3):

Solution is this:

```
minikube delete
minikube start --vm-driver none
```