# How to start with kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have two IP'S master node and worker node? I need to deploy some services using these. I don't know anything about kubernetes ,what is master node and worker node?

How do I start?

Comment: The [kubernetes tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kubernetes/info) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Can you tell me one thing why kubectl works on master node but on worker node , it gives "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Comment: Maybe [did you specify the right host or port? error on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36650642/205233) has the answer to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start from the very basic things..

[Kubernetes concept page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/) is your starting point.

> The Kubernetes Master is a collection of three processes that run on a
>   single node in your cluster, which is designated as the master node.
>   Those processes are: kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and
>   kube-scheduler. 
>   Each individual non-master node in your cluster runs
>   two processes: kubelet, which communicates with the Kubernetes Master.
>   kube-proxy, a network proxy which reflects Kubernetes networking
>   services on each node.

Regarding you question in comment: read [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/). Make sure you have kubeconfig file in the right place..