# segmentation fault occurs when trying to start minikube in ubuntu

Tags: docker, kubernetes, segmentation-fault, kubectl, minikube

`$ minikube start
Segmentation fault`

`$ kubectl version`

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Facing this kind of error when trying to start minikube on ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [did you specify the right host or port? error on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650642/did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port-error-on-kubernetes)

Comment: Without you providing one iota of information about your system, including where you got `minikube`, whether it has ever worked before, and the output of running `minikube start` with debug logging, no one can possibly help you