# Any command type in kubernetes gives error "The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused"

Tags: linux, kubernetes

If I execute the **kubectl get pods** command, I get the following error.

> [root@localhost docker]# kubectl get pods
> E0828 07:50:09.102620 1054506 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
> E0828 07:50:09.102983 1054506 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
> E0828 07:50:09.104380 1054506 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
> E0828 07:50:09.105397 1054506 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
> E0828 07:50:09.106718 1054506 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

If you run the three commands below one by one, an error occurs when you execute the second command.

```
  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

After executing **sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config** this command, I got the below error.

> [root@localhost docker]# sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
> cp: cannot stat '/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: could you explain with more detail which kubernetes distro you are using (e.g. k8s, k3s, etc.) and where your cluster is located and from where you want to access you cluster? Then I can provide you with a detailed answer on how to solve your problem!

Comment: Hi @OberwalderSven I'm using k8s and want to access the cluster from the same machine running kubenetes

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming-related question.  [did you specify the right host or port? error on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650642/did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port-error-on-kubernetes) isn't necessarily on-topic either, but it does seem to cover this same error.